# How to do local front-end SPA development against an OIDC endpoint without localhost as a callback URL?

Tags: security, openid-connect, auth0

In its readiness checks, Auth0 strongly suggests *not* having localhost domains as allowed callback URLs.

When developing front-end code, chances are it will be served by a local dev server, e.g. at `http://localhost:3000`. This means that to authenticate when developing, the OIDC provider must allow a redirect to `http://localhost:3000`.

Are Auth0's warnings about localhost legitimate?

What are some good solutions for handling these conflicting requirements?

---

*Note: This question is about Auth0, but the problem applies to building SPAs with OIDC in general.*

Comment: You should not use the same user pool (I never used Auth0 and don't know what it's called there, the same IdP "entity") for production and development. In production you should not have localhost as an allowed callback, but in your dev instance it's fine.

Comment: But this means that you cannot test a production account against the production API with a local front-end.

Comment: When developping on my localhost, I attack a "dev" ADFS-OIDC with dedicated secret & client id and where localhost and port 80 are authorised as referer. When I go into pre-production and finally into production, localhost is obviously not authorised in either case and SSL is mandatory. That's how we manage it.

Comment: @sdgfsdh Unfortunately, yes, the security best practice is not to use production accounts in development. Creating appropriate test data (either by generating it, or more commonly, anonymizing / desensitizing production data for testing in a secure, reliable way) is a feat of its own. Using production data even if you are testing frontend is a risk. Actually, in the old-school model, development shouldn't even have access to prod data. :) In today's world that's not how it works anymore in many companies, but regularly using prod for testing is still not advisable.